# How to make a script delete a directory after checking for its existence?

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

How might one make a bash script which when run will check for the existence of a file/folder and if the file/folder is there remove it?

Comment: Why do you need to check for existence first?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846007/check-if-directory-exists-and-delete-in-one-command-unix

Answer (score 5):

There's no point in testing if it exists or not, `rm -rf` already does that for you. If it exists, `rm` removes it. If it doesn't exist, `rm` considers the job already done, and just returns with success.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm -rf "$@"
```

Which also means there's not really any point in the script, since you can just run  `rm -rf /some/dir` instead of  `scriptname /some/dir`.

Comment: when I type `rmdir /some/nonexistent/directory` it says `could not remove "/some/nonexistent/directory": No such file or directory`

Comment: @It'sWillem, sure. `rmdir` and `rm` do different things and behave differently.

Answer (score 4):

Simple if statement with `rm -rf` command

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e "$1" ];then rm -rf "$1" ; fi
```

Comment: As stated in another answer here, rm -rf already takes care of everything itself.  No need for a fancy script.